# After PDFs combined, copied text using Inter font is gibberish

Tags: pdf, preview, font

I have been making multi-page PDFs from Sketch. Each page is exported as a PDF. Then I combine these pages into one PDF using a Quick Action, either the built in Create PDF action, or a homemade one of my own.

[image]

Here is the problem. After combining files this way, any text with the font [Inter](https://rsms.me/inter/) causes problems. It is displayed in Preview correctly, but copying text results in gibberish and I'm being told it renders incorrectly on other computers. I've tested this with Helvetica Neue and this font works properly.

Here is the text before using a Quick Action:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris luctus est odio, efficitur aliquet justo vulputate nec. Sed gravida, quam at lacinia suscipit, lacus augue finibus turpis, ut ullamcorper augue erat vel mauris. Sed porta eget nisi sit amet viverra. Aliquam eget orci massa. Nulla imperdiet quis augue vel blandit. Donec et accumsan nulla. Nam vel diam erat.

And here that same text after using a Quick Action then selecting and copying it

> '!"#$% '()*% +","# )'- .%$-/ 0"1)$0-$-*# .+'(')0'12 $,'-3 4.*5') ,*0-*) $)- "+'"/ $66'0'-*# .,'7*$- 8*)-" 9*,(*-.-$ 1$03 :$+ 2#.9'+./ 7*.% .- ,.0'1'. )*)0'('-/ ,.0*) .*2*$ 6'1';*) -*#(')/ *- *,,.%0"#($# .*2*$ $#.- 9$, %.*5')3 :$+ ("5-. $2$- 1')' )'- .%$- 9'9$5#.3 <,'7*.% $2$- "#0' %.)).3 =*,,. '%($#+'$- 7*') .*2*$ 9$, ;,.1+'-3 >"1$0 $- .00*%).1 1*,,.3 =.% 9$, +'.% $#.-3'

What is causing this and how can I make sure this font works properly after using Quick Actions?

Comment: why don't you just change the font?

Comment: Ask the folks who made that font.  May be a bug in one of the internal tables.

Comment: Good idea @TomGewecke. I've reached out to them.

Comment: you could try PDFSam application and see how it merges. PDFSam stands for PDF Split and Merge. It's a free app you can run on your Mac.  https://pdfsam.org